# getting error when closing the script problem

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know what is problem in this code .it runs perfectly
in script .but after closing the program it shows this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3.9\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\NK Infosystem\PycharmProjects\password tkinter\main.py", line 225, in login_in
    if uni_username.get() == u_name and uni_pass.get() == u_pass:
  File "C:\python3.9\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3040, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"
```

and 225 line is this

```
    cursr.execute("SELECT rowid ,* FROM usernameandpassword")
    user_and_pass = (cursr.fetchall())

    for users in user_and_pass:

        u_name = (users[1])
        u_pass = (users[2])

        if uni_username.get() == u_name and uni_pass.get() == u_pass:
            show_new_user_window()

    uni_username.delete(0, "end")
    uni_pass.delete(0, "end")


save_uni_pass_and_name = Button(mainscreen, text="Save", command=save_uni_ones, padx=30, bg="blue2", fg="gold").place(
    x=113, y=170, anchor="c")
login_butt = Button(mainscreen, text="Login", padx=30, command=login_in, bg="blue2", fg="gold").place(x=213, y=170,
                                                                                                      anchor="c")
connection.commit()

mainscreen.mainloop()
```

full code is at patch1 branch
https://github.com/aadityabaj/python-projects.git

Comment: It is because you called `mainloop()` twice.  Remove the `mainloop()` inside `show_new_user_window()`.  Also use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` inside the function as well.

Comment: now 4 windows pop up after removing 2nd mainloop

Comment: can you say some words about my code , like how it is

Comment: More than one window shown up because the table `usernameandpassword` does not have an unique column so that same `username` and `password` can be saved more than once.  You need to set the `username` column as the `PRIMARY KEY` column.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not a problem: The error says that python tries to get the input of an Entry that doesn't exist (anymore). When you close the window, you destroy also the Entry. So actually I think It's nothing to worry about.

Tip:
when you try to add a `mainscreen.quit()` command.

I've seen this problem before and I hope it's helping you.

#### update 1

you could make a button to quit and add it to a function or just add it to some hotkeys or to an if-statement.

if my answer is helpful, please vote it up, because at 50 points of the reputation I can use comments and that's very handy. I've now 40

Comment: where so i put mainscreen.quit()